What's the oldest known example of an 'overpass'?
Bridges have been around since ancient times to get over obstacles that can't easily be crossed, like rivers or crevasses.
What is the oldest known example of a bridge specifically built to pass traffic over other traffic?
That is, a level junction could have been built and would have been easier, but a bridge (or bonus, tunnel) was built instead.
Excluded are:

Bridges that cross other routes by happenstance or necessity, like a bridge over a canal including a towpath, or a bridge over a steep valley that has a road through it. The crossing of the two travel routes needs to be the primary purpose

Bridges built for security or access control reasons, like a gatehouse in fortified walls.

Bridges to remove the need for a level change - a hallway through an upper floor of a building isn't an 'overpass' merely because there's a hallway on a lower floor below it. The same for a canal-over-river/canal crossing where a bridge avoids constructing locks.


I'm open to any traffic types or combinations that could have crossed at a level. For example, two roads, foot traffic and railway, or even two canals.
Wikipedia gives an example as:

The world's first railroad flyover was constructed in 1843 by the London and Croydon Railway at Norwood Junction railway station to carry its atmospheric railway vehicles over the Brighton Main Line.

It seems likely an older non-railway example exists.

@njuffa Same or different type of traffic, as long as they could have crossed at a level. So road over rail, pedestrians over carts, but not carts over a canal. I saw a post a while back about ancient Rome having quite bad traffic, and was curious whether any attempt had been made to grade-separate.

@njuffa I assumed that a railway wasn't going to have been first because the shallow gradients mean you need long approaches to climb/descend, whereas horse-and-cart can I think climb steeper gradients.

I'm not sure why this was closed? The answer I gave in the comments is basically the same as the paragraph under the bullet points, and seems to answer the only clarification requested.

It is unlikely that a pre-railway example exists. This is beccause pre-industrial traffic was neither dense nor frequent enough to need an overpass. Horse-drawn transport could cross any other land thoroughfare by simply passing through it at a regular junction with virtually no delay. It wasn't until a new kind of "thoroughfare" (the railway track) came into being that bridges were required.
Of course if you accept canals as transport there were plenty of "overpasses" over those.

@DJClayworth - including canal over canal if I recall properly - one of those might be the answer.

The oldest bridge taking a street over a canal is probably High Bridge in Lincoln, constructed in 1160. It takes Lincoln High Street over the Witham Navigation (also called Witham Navigable Drains)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigable_aqueduct - canal over river an option? Hard to tell if some of the early ones were over generally navigable rivers.

@JonCuster Navigable aqueduct could be an option! As you say, it needs to be a) over a navigable river, but also b) close enough in height to the river that locks down into and back up from the river could have been an option (see third bullet).

@DJClayworth A footbridge/roadbridge over a canal is something I excluded in paragraph 3 because they can't meet at a level crossing.

Then I think you are going to get the answer "No". Because before railways roads and canals (and rivers) were pretty much the only kinds of transportation routes. Roads can always meet on a level, and until highways there wasn't enough traffic to ever go to the expense of building a road-over-road bridge.

That was my original assumption, but I asked the question to see if there were any counterexamples. I have also seen a few posts suggesting that Roman traffic could actually be very severe, and was curious whether that ever resulted in attempts to grade-separate.
